# Upload to Google Cloud Storage via signed URL - object not publicly readable

Tags: google-cloud-storage, acl, pre-signed-url

I followed up [this](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs) tutorial to allow upload of files from GWT frontend directly to Google Cloud Storage using signed URLs. I've extended the Java example by specifying content type which worked just fine. Then, I saw that files uploaded this way weren't publicly readable. To get this working I've tried:

- I've set up default ACL for newly uploaded objects `gsutil defacl set public-read gs://<bucket>`. Uploaded file again - no luck, stil not visible.
- Then tried to set ACL on that object directly `gsutil acl set public-read  gs://<bucket>/<file>` but it gave me **AccessDeniedException: 403 Forbidden**. It makes sense since gsutil is authenticated with my Google account and signed URL is being created with service account and it's P12 key.
- I've tried to set up ACL at upload phase therefore added `"x-goog-acl:public-read\n"` canonicalized extension headers and appropriate query string param to pass signature check. Damn, stil no luck!

My assumption is that maybe this extension header I'm using is wrong? Then according to documentation all authenticated requests to GCS will apply `private` ACL by default.

Anyway - why I can't make these files publicly readable from Google Console when I'm logged in as project owner? I can make so for all files uploaded through console (I know that in that case the owner is project owner and not the service account).

What I'm doing wrong? How can I make them publicly readable by anyone?

Thanks in advice!

Comment: Sounds like you are not the owner of the bucket or the object. It is possible to be the project owner but not the owner of GCS buckets/files. If you go in the console and click on the 3 dots on the right of the bucket and click edit permission. Is your service account listed as owner? I was running into a similar problem playing around with it and it worked after adding me service account as an owner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you gone through the given [docs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#Signed-URLs). It clearly mention that, if you need the user to download the object without using the google account then this method provides an assigned URL for specific time to the User to download the object. I am assuming that might be its not possible to make those objects publicly available as they are signed. If still you need that functionality I would recommend you to go through the resumable upload or simple upload of the object.

Also try to put the service account of your project as the owner in the "Edit default permission of Object" in the developer console on the right side of your bucket name.

Comment: You're right - hard to require unauthed access from authed resource. However I was able to achieve that by adding "owner" to "allUsers" in default permissions which made it possible to overwrite object but also download without auth.